# external javascript call fail

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a small website for learning purposes. My problem is that I can't call a .js file located in the same folder of my .html document.

Since it seemd to me that I have a configuration problem, I started over with two basic files so to reduce the possibility of typos, etc.

I followed this step by step and very easy tutorial:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptexternal.php

But it does not work (I mean that .js file does not run)

Here is the html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="standalone.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click Me!">
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code within the external .js

```
function popup() {
alert("Hi, this is a test!")
}
```

Firebug just shows me this text when I click the button: "popup();"

Both html and js documents are in same folder.

I had a look at some issues similar to mine, but they do not apply.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using "javascript:popup();" instead.  You may also want to wrap your button inside a FORM tag.

Comment: can you change the browser and told us the result.

Comment: I don't see any problem given what you've shown us.  Double check the file names.  Your external file should be called `standalone.js`.

Comment: Alerts may be blocked in your browser. Try also `console.log()` method.

Comment: I actually solved by writing only this into the .js file:                                  alert("Hi this is a test");    No need for the function popup().   Many thanks to all of you!